# I can not take Switch parameter as an array. for instance

Tags: powershell-4.0

$b= 1,4,6
SWITCH($b)
    {

```
  1 {"Reviewers are Waheed"}
  2 {"Reviewers are amjad"}
  3 {"Reviewers are basil"}
  4 {"Reviewers are ehsan"}
  5 {"Reviewers are Ali"}
  6 {"Reviewers are chupachoops"}
  7 {"Reviewers are poopapoops"}
  8 {"Reviewers are leelo leer"}
  9 {"Reviewers are chuwara"} 
}
```

## This code shall echo the right output, that i want.

Reviewers are Waheed
Reviewers are ehsan
Reviewers are chupachoops

but if i go like,

SWITCH($b = read-host "Enter No: ")
    {

```
  1 {"Reviewers are Waheed"}
  2 {"Reviewers are amjad"}
  3 {"Reviewers are basil"}
  4 {"Reviewers are ehsan"}
  5 {"Reviewers are Ali"}
  6 {"Reviewers are chupachoops"}
  7 {"Reviewers are poopapoops"}
  8 {"Reviewers are leelo leer"}
  9 {"Reviewers are chuwara"} 
}
```

Now if the user Enters, <1,2,7> i should be getting the right output, output that corresponds to the respective switch case, but How ever i'm not getting anything as output, Can any one Help??

Answer (score 0):

You can check with get-member what your variable contains, it is really useful to troubleshoot this kind of problems. By default the read-host will convert your input to an int32 in this case, and you don't want that. You can force your input to be a string and then split it to read each value in the switch as bellow :

```
[string]$b = read-host "Enter No: "
SWITCH($b.Split(",")) {

1 {"Reviewers are Waheed"}
2 {"Reviewers are amjad"}
3 {"Reviewers are basil"}
4 {"Reviewers are ehsan"}
5 {"Reviewers are Ali"}
6 {"Reviewers are chupachoops"}
7 {"Reviewers are poopapoops"}
8 {"Reviewers are leelo leer"}
9 {"Reviewers are chuwara"} 
}
```

Comment: thanks @2o1o0 this totally works and is now functional.
appreciate your support. :)

Comment: If it helped, please don't forget to flag the answer accordingly! ;)

Comment: Will do for sure, once i get my reputation above 15, i tried up voting your answer, but apparently i'm not just a switch noob. :P :) @2o1o0